# Serverless - Unable to find good bind path format

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I keep getting the following error when trying to run serverless deploy with python:

"Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.7

Error --------------------------------------------------

Unable to find good bind path format"

I am building a simple serverless application for learning purposes. I have Windows 10 Home, Serverless 1.49.0, Python 3.7 and Docker Toolbox for windows version 18.09.3. The problem seems to come when I install and add serverless-python-requirements in the serverless.yml because I think Serverless tries to find Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.7 but can't find it.

I have tried most of the solutions I found on the internet, including unmounting and remounting the C drive in VirtualBox. I have also made sure that I'm setting up and running my virtual environment with Python 3.7. Furthermore, I also completely uninstalled VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox because I had VirtualBox beforehand and reinstalled them together.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Do I need to use something called Lambda Layers? Do need to figure out why serverless can't find the Docker Image?

httprequest.py:

```
import requests
def handler(event, context):
    r = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/news")
    return {"content": r.text}
```

requirements.txt:

```
requests
```

serverless.yml:

```
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: my-serverless-project
#app: your-app-name
#tenant: your-tenant-name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

# you can overwrite defaults here
#  stage: dev
#  region: us-east-1

# you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
#  iamRoleStatements:
#    - Effect: "Allow"
#      Action:
#        - "s3:ListBucket"
#      Resource: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "ServerlessDeploymentBucket" } ] ]  }
#    - Effect: "Allow"
#      Action:
#        - "s3:PutObject"
#      Resource:
#        Fn::Join:
#          - ""
#          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
#            - "Ref" : "ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
#            - "/*"

# you can define service wide environment variables here
#  environment:
#    variable1: value1

# you can add packaging information here
#package:
#  include:
#    - include-me.py
#    - include-me-dir/**
#  exclude:
#    - exclude-me.py
#    - exclude-me-dir/**

functions:
  hello:
    handler: hello.handler #handler.hello
  httprequest:
    handler: httprequest.handler
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
#    events:
#      - http:
#          path: users/create
#          method: get
#      - websocket: $connect
#      - s3: ${env:BUCKET}
#      - schedule: rate(10 minutes)
#      - sns: greeter-topic
#      - stream: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:XXXXXX:table/foo/stream/1970-01-01T00:00:00.000
#      - alexaSkill: amzn1.ask.skill.xx-xx-xx-xx
#      - alexaSmartHome: amzn1.ask.skill.xx-xx-xx-xx
#      - iot:
#          sql: "SELECT * FROM 'some_topic'"
#      - cloudwatchEvent:
#          event:
#            source:
#              - "aws.ec2"
#            detail-type:
#              - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
#            detail:
#              state:
#                - pending
#      - cloudwatchLog: '/aws/lambda/hello'
#      - cognitoUserPool:
#          pool: MyUserPool
#          trigger: PreSignUp
#      - alb:
#          listenerArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXXXX:listener/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188/
#          priority: 1
#          conditions:
#            host: example.com
#            path: /hello

#    Define function environment variables here
#    environment:
#      variable2: value2

# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
#resources:
#  Resources:
#    NewResource:
#      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
#      Properties:
#        BucketName: my-new-bucket
#  Outputs:
#     NewOutput:
#       Description: "Description for the output"
#       Value: "Some output value"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    pythonBin: python
```

Full Error Message:

```
Serverless: Generated requirements from C:\Users\devsh\Documents\Weavr.ai\serverless-python-examples\my-serverless-project\requirements.txt in C:\Users\devsh\Documents\Weavr.ai\serverless-python-examples\my-serverless-project\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from C:\Users\devsh\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\ac29cf94cb1c93e391c7ddeed69c617107314d90a8c00896218e173eb21a4342_slspyc\requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.7

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Unable to find good bind path format

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              8.11.3
     Serverless Version:        1.49.0
     Enterprise Plugin Version: 1.3.8
     Platform SDK Version:      2.1.0
```

Comment: I never used docker toolset, but sometimes I have the same problem as you using this plugin. The solution I found for my case is to unmount and remount the C drive (considering that it's your main drive) e restarting docker for Windows afterwards. Since you use Windows Home, I believe you cannot install docker for Windows in your machine, but it would be a good test to understand if it can solve your problem or not (if you have an available compatible machine, of course). Did you already found any solutions?

Comment: Yeah I fixed the problem using this (found on github): Sometimes your Python executable isn't available on your $PATH as python2.7 or python3.6 (for example, windows or using pyenv). To support this, this plugin has the following option:

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    pythonBin: /opt/python3.6/bin/python     

https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#checkered_flag-windows-dockerizepip-notes